# Prevent the 'signtool.exe' command from running when a certificate is not available

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, signtool

I am adding the following to post-build command line in a build event to sign the application EXE file with a certificate:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\signtool.exe" sign /t "http://timestamp.digicert.com" /n "XXX INC" "$(ProjectDir)obj\x86\Debug\app.exe"
```

How can I prevent this line from executing when the certificate "XXX INC" is not available?

Comment: Because I am working on a team, some pc does not have the certificate, so they cannot compile the application.

Comment: Personally, I'd avoid the problem by having multiple configurations, some which sign, some which don't sign. Only the PC that has the certificate uses the configuration that signs the executable. But that doesn't actually answer the question you asked, which may still be of interest.

Comment: This makes little sense.  You only sign the release build, the final one.  There's no point in signing a debug build, the kind that the devs work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [IF EXIST](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/if.php) batch statement. I'm not sure if you can add it directly to the PostBuild event, but you can easilly create a .bat file, insert all commands there and call it in your project's PostBuild event.